# How to find the text between ( and )

Tags: java, regex

I have a few strings which are like this:

```
text (255)
varchar (64)    
...
```

I want to find out the number between ( and ) and store that in a string. That is, obviously, store these lengths in strings. 
I have the rest of it figured out except for the regex parsing part.
I'm having trouble figuring out the regex pattern.

How do I do this?

The sample code is going to look like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<I CANT FIGURE OUT WHAT COMES HERE>").matcher("text (255)");
```

Also, I'd like to know if there's a cheat sheet for regex parsing, from where one can directly pick up the regex patterns

Comment: Have you tried anything? *a cheat sheet for regex parsing* - Sorry, hard luck. Regex is an art, that comes by practice. You don't have a dictionary.

Comment: Don't use a regex for something *so* simple. This is basically one of the meanings of jwz's famous "now you have two problems."

Comment: @RohitJain I understand, but at times, you cannot be a master of all arts and cheat sheets come in handy! 
and I DID find a good cheat sheet for regex parsing, just in case someone's interested!
http://www.vijayforvictory.com/technology/regular-expression-cheat-sheet-for-programmers/2518/

Comment: You don't even need the text between the parens, you just need the digits.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use a plain string match

```
String s = "text (255)";
int start = s.indexOf('(')+1;
int end = s.indexOf(')', start);
if (end < 0) {
    // not found
} else {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(start, end));
}
```

You can use regex as sometimes this makes your code simpler, but that doesn't mean you should in all cases.  I suspect this is one where a simple string indexOf and substring will not only be faster, and shorter but more importantly, easier to understand.

Comment: A thousand times this.

Comment: Even better, `s.lastIndexOf(')', start)` to capture "nested" parenthesis pairs.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I couldn't decided if this was better here, but you are right that in other cases lastIndexOf might be best.

Comment: It always depends on requirements (of course), but this is obviously SQL, and if "reused" for table definitions, then the nesting would be very important `create table foo ( .... );`

Comment: Thanks for the info! Much appreciated. I'm taking this as the answer! :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this pattern to match *any text* between parentheses:

```
\(([^)]*)\)
```

Or this to match just numbers (with possible whitespace padding):

```
\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)
```

Of course, to use this in a string literal, you have to escape the `\` characters:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\)")...
```

Comment: Given that it looks like SQL, allowing for spaces as well might be wise.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some example code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt="varchar (64)";

    String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re2="\\((\\d+)\\)";  // Round Braces 1

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String rbraces1=m.group(1);
        System.out.print("("+rbraces1.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
  }
}
```

This will print out any `(int)` it finds in the input string, `txt`.

The regex is `\((\d+)\)` to match any numbers between `()`

Answer (score 2):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)\\)").matcher("text (255)");
if (m.find()) {
    int len = Integer.parseInt (m.group(1));
    System.out.println (len);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int index1  = string.indexOf("(")
int index2  = string.indexOf(")")

String intValue = string.substring(index1+1, index2-1);
```